# Can someone help me further into this Galaga game?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, recursion, arraylist

I started on this galaga program for a computer science assignment at school a little while back, but just got to working hard on it today, basically I have all the drawing down of everything (yes im going to add more Enemy ships, but everything else is set even though the code is messy (yes i know its not the best, but for now, it works). The next problem into the game is collisions. my current idea is to have several arrays, one for each enemy ship, the arrays would include x and y coordination, so if the laser his a point listed in the array, the 'Ship1Explosion' will become true (change from original false) and that will draw the ship1's explosion (I know how to do that) as well as changing boolean Ship1 to false, so that ship wont continue to redraw over and over.

**Error I'm getting**:

```
   error: int cannot be dereferenced
   int h = Ship1area.charAt(l);
```

If anyone can please help me, i'd love the help as to setting up the collision from the laser. Let me know if i need to explain anything else, thank you.

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
public class Galaga extends Applet implements KeyListener
{   
public static int x1 = 500;
public static int y1 = 400;
public static int bx = x1+73;
public static int by = y1+45;
public static int bx1 = x1+73;
public static int by1 = y1+100;
public static int by2 = by-40;
public static int by3 = by-50;
public static int x = 200;
public static int y = 0;
public static int j = 262;
public static int p;
public static int h;
public static int Ship1area;
public boolean keyUp;
public boolean keyDown;
public boolean keyLeft;
public boolean keyRight;
public boolean keySpace;
public boolean Laser = false;
public boolean Ship1Explosion = false;
public boolean Ship1 = true;

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    DrawBackground(g);
    addKeyListener(this);
    this.DrawGalaga(g,x1,y1);
    DrawShip1(g);
    DrawLaser(g);
    DrawShip1Explosion(g);
}
public void DrawBackground(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(1,2,3000,4000);
    DrawStars(g);
}
public void DrawGalaga(Graphics g, int x1, int y1)
{       
        {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine(x1+42,y1+75,x1+42,y1+80); //Far Left Gun
        g.drawLine(x1+43,y1+75,x1+43,y1+80);
        g.drawLine(x1+44,y1+75,x1+44,y1+80);
        g.drawLine(x1+45,y1+75,x1+45,y1+80);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawLine(x1+42,y1+80,x1+42,y1+100); //Far Left Piece
        g.drawLine(x1+43,y1+80,x1+43,y1+100);
        g.drawLine(x1+44,y1+80,x1+44,y1+100);
        g.drawLine(x1+45,y1+80,x1+45,y1+100);

        g.drawLine(x1+46,y1+83,x1+46,y1+96); //From Left, 1st one
        g.drawLine(x1+47,y1+83,x1+47,y1+96);
        g.drawLine(x1+48,y1+83,x1+48,y1+96);
        g.drawLine(x1+49,y1+83,x1+49,y1+96);

        g.drawLine(x1+50,y1+79,x1+50,y1+92); //From Left, 2nd one
        g.drawLine(x1+51,y1+79,x1+51,y1+92);
        g.drawLine(x1+52,y1+79,x1+52,y1+92);
        g.drawLine(x1+53,y1+79,x1+53,y1+92);    

        g.drawLine(x1+54,y1+65,x1+54,y1+89); //From Left, 3rd one
        g.drawLine(x1+55,y1+65,x1+55,y1+89);
        g.drawLine(x1+56,y1+65,x1+56,y1+89);
        g.drawLine(x1+57,y1+65,x1+57,y1+89);

        g.drawLine(x1+58,y1+75,x1+58,y1+89); //From Middle 3rd one
        g.drawLine(x1+59,y1+75,x1+59,y1+89);
        g.drawLine(x1+60,y1+75,x1+60,y1+89);
        g.drawLine(x1+61,y1+75,x1+61,y1+89);

        g.drawLine(x1+62,y1+70,x1+62,y1+85); //From Middle, 2nd Left one
        g.drawLine(x1+63,y1+70,x1+63,y1+85);
        g.drawLine(x1+64,y1+70,x1+64,y1+85);
        g.drawLine(x1+65,y1+70,x1+65,y1+85);
        g.drawLine(x1+66,y1+60,x1+66,y1+95); //From Middle, 1st Left one
        g.drawLine(x1+67,y1+60,x1+67,y1+95);
        g.drawLine(x1+68,y1+60,x1+68,y1+95);
        g.drawLine(x1+69,y1+60,x1+69,y1+95);

        g.drawLine(x1+70,y1+45,x1+70,y1+100); //Big Middle Piece
        g.drawLine(x1+71,y1+45,x1+71,y1+100);
        g.drawLine(x1+72,y1+45,x1+72,y1+100);
        g.drawLine(bx,by,bx1,by1);
        g.drawLine(x1+74,y1+45,x1+74,y1+100);
        g.drawLine(x1+75,y1+45,x1+75,y1+100);
        g.drawLine(x1+76,y1+45,x1+76,y1+100);

        g.drawLine(x1+77,y1+60,x1+77,y1+95); //From Middle, 1st Right one
        g.drawLine(x1+78,y1+60,x1+78,y1+95);
        g.drawLine(x1+79,y1+60,x1+79,y1+95);
        g.drawLine(x1+80,y1+60,x1+80,y1+95);

        g.drawLine(x1+81,y1+70,x1+81,y1+85); //From Middle, 2nd Right one
        g.drawLine(x1+82,y1+70,x1+82,y1+85);
        g.drawLine(x1+83,y1+70,x1+83,y1+85);
        g.drawLine(x1+84,y1+70,x1+84,y1+85);

        g.drawLine(x1+85,y1+75,x1+85,y1+89); //From Middle 3rd one
        g.drawLine(x1+86,y1+75,x1+86,y1+89);
        g.drawLine(x1+87,y1+75,x1+87,y1+89);
        g.drawLine(x1+88,y1+75,x1+88,y1+89);

        g.drawLine(x1+88,y1+65,x1+88,y1+89); //From Right, 3rd one
        g.drawLine(x1+89,y1+65,x1+89,y1+89);
        g.drawLine(x1+90,y1+65,x1+90,y1+89);
        g.drawLine(x1+91,y1+65,x1+91,y1+89);

        g.drawLine(x1+92,y1+79,x1+92,y1+92); //From Right, 2nd one
        g.drawLine(x1+93,y1+79,x1+93,y1+92);
        g.drawLine(x1+94,y1+79,x1+94,y1+92);
        g.drawLine(x1+95,y1+79,x1+95,y1+92);

        g.drawLine(x1+96,y1+83,x1+96,y1+96); //From Right, 1st one
        g.drawLine(x1+97,y1+83,x1+97,y1+96);
        g.drawLine(x1+98,y1+83,x1+98,y1+96);
        g.drawLine(x1+99,y1+83,x1+99,y1+96);

        g.drawLine(x1+100,y1+80,x1+100,y1+100); //Far Right Piece
        g.drawLine(x1+101,y1+80,x1+101,y1+100);
        g.drawLine(x1+102,y1+80,x1+102,y1+100);
        g.drawLine(x1+103,y1+80,x1+103,y1+100);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine(x1+100,y1+75,x1+100,y1+80); //Far Right Gun
        g.drawLine(x1+101,y1+75,x1+101,y1+80);
        g.drawLine(x1+102,y1+75,x1+102,y1+80);
        g.drawLine(x1+103,y1+75,x1+103,y1+80);
    }
}
public void DrawShip1(Graphics g)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    if(Ship1)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        Polygon Ship1 = new Polygon();
        Ship1.addPoint(x+268,y+190); //1
        Ship1.addPoint(x+270,y+190);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+270,y+185);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+275,y+185);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+275,y+155); //5
        Ship1.addPoint(x+278,y+155);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+278,y+150);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+285,y+150);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+285,y+165);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+293,y+165); //10
        Ship1.addPoint(x+293,y+150);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+301,y+150);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+301,y+165); 
        Ship1.addPoint(x+309,y+165);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+309,y+150); //15
        Ship1.addPoint(x+317,y+150);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+317,y+155);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+319,y+155);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+319,y+185);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+325,y+185); //20
        Ship1.addPoint(x+325,y+190);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+323,y+190);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+323,y+185);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+330,y+185);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+330,y+155); //25
        Ship1.addPoint(x+325,y+155);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+325,y+145);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+330,y+145);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+330,y+140);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+316,y+140); //30
        Ship1.addPoint(x+316,y+135);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+311,y+135);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+311,y+130);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+306,y+130);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+306,y+125); //35
        Ship1.addPoint(x+311,y+125);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+311,y+120);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+316,y+120);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+316,y+115);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+306,y+115); //40
        Ship1.addPoint(x+306,y+100);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+298,y+100);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+298,y+115);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+290,y+115);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+290,y+100); //45
        Ship1.addPoint(x+282,y+100);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+282,y+115);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+272,y+115);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+272,y+120);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+277,y+120); //50
        Ship1.addPoint(x+277,y+125);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+282,y+125);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+282,y+130);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+277,y+130);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+277,y+135); //55
        Ship1.addPoint(x+272,y+135);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+272,y+140);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+262,y+140);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+262,y+145);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+267,y+145); //60
        Ship1.addPoint(x+267,y+145);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+272,y+145);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+272,y+155);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+265,y+155);
        Ship1.addPoint(x+265,y+185); //61
        Ship1.addPoint(x+268,y+185);
        g.fillPolygon(Ship1);
        Polygon Ship1parts1 = new Polygon();
        g.setColor(Color.pink);
        Ship1parts1.addPoint(x+268,y+180);
        Ship1parts1.addPoint(x+272,y+180);
        Ship1parts1.addPoint(x+272,y+170);
        Ship1parts1.addPoint(x+270,y+170);
        Ship1parts1.addPoint(x+270,y+165);
        Ship1parts1.addPoint(x+268,y+165);
        Ship1parts1.addPoint(x+268,y+180);
        g.fillPolygon(Ship1parts1);
        Polygon Ship1parts2 = new Polygon();
        Ship1parts2.addPoint(x+330,y+180);
        Ship1parts2.addPoint(x+324,y+180);
        Ship1parts2.addPoint(x+324,y+170);
        Ship1parts2.addPoint(x+326,y+170);
        Ship1parts2.addPoint(x+326,y+165);
        Ship1parts2.addPoint(x+328,y+165);
        Ship1parts2.addPoint(x+328,y+180);
        g.fillPolygon(Ship1parts2);
        }
}
public void DrawStars(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    int x, y;
    for (int s = 0; s < 2000; s++) 
        {
            x = (int)(Math.random()*2000);
            y = (int)(Math.random()*2000); 
            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
        }
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        x1--;
        bx--;
        bx1--;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        x1++;
        bx++;
        bx1++;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        y1--;
        by--;
        by1--;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        y1++;
        by++;
        by1++;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
    {
        Laser = true;
    }
        repaint();
}
public void DrawLaser(Graphics g)
{
    if (Laser)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        outerloop:
            for(int i=0;i<=1000; i+=5)
            {
                for(int j=262;j<=330;j+=1)
                {
                    ArrayList Ship1area = new ArrayList();
                    Ship1area.add(j);
                }
                g.drawLine(bx,by2,bx,by3);
                delay(1);
                repaint();
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawLine(bx,by2,bx,by3);
                by2--;
                by3--;
                by2--;
                by3--;
                by2--;
                by3--;
                g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                g.drawLine(bx,by2,bx,by3);
                if(by2 <= 0)
                    break outerloop;
                for (int l=0;l<=p;l++)
                    {
                    int h = Ship1area.charAt(l);
                    if(h == bx)
                        {   
                            Ship1Explosion = true;
                        }
                    }
        }
        by2 = by-60;
        by3 = by-70;
    }
}
public void DrawShip1Explosion(Graphics g)
{
    if (Ship1Explosion)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawLine(100,100,200,200);
        }
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{   
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
    {
        Laser = false;
    }
    keyUp = keyDown = keyLeft = keyRight = keySpace = false;
    repaint();
}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{
}   
public void delay (int n)
{
    long startDelay = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long endDelay=0;
    while (endDelay - startDelay < n)
    endDelay = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This line that to which you refer:

```
int h = ship1area.charAt(l);
```

is referring to an `int` value at the class level. You probably want the `ArrayList` of the same name(!) which in the `for` loop in the `drawLaser` method. In that case you would need:

```
int h = (int) ship1area.get(l);
```

The `ArrayList` will have to be moved out of the `for` to the scope of the method to be visible. i.e.

```
public void drawLaser(Graphics g) {

   ArrayList<String> ship1area = new ArrayList<>();
   ...
```

Aside: Given Java naming conventions, variable & method names typically start with a *lowercase* letter.